# Use template value for class name as pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I want to send a "ping" to another object to see if it is alive. This is primarily for testing during development. I wound up writing the same code over and over, so I am looking at how to template it. Here is my code (that doesn't work yet):

```
template<class T>
bool pingTest(T) {
    return T.ping();  // <<< HOW DO I FORM THIS LINE?
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped, checkmark it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're supposed to add an instance:

```
template<class T>
bool pingTest(T& instance) {
    return instance.ping();  // <<< HOW DO I FORM THIS LINE?
}
```

or, even better: Make `ping` static so that no instance of `T` needs to be passed into the function, thereby saving memory and time:

```
template<class T>
bool pingTest() {
    return T::ping();  // <<< HOW DO I FORM THIS LINE?
}
```

Comment: You may want to re-read your answer, I think you mixed something up when editing :)

Comment: @Jarod42 that's true, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

`T` is just a type name, but there's no instance (object) of this type to run this method on.

```
template<class T>
bool pingTest(T o) {
 return o.ping();
}
```

Can you do `int` + `int`? No, you cannot, but you can add two integers values:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
a + b;             // a meaningful expression
```

Likewise, if `T` denoted a type that exposes the function `ping`, you can call it on an object of type `T`, but not on `T` itself, unless, of course, `ping` is a static function.